# updating view when data in database changes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, data-binding

I have a problem with project iam working on. In one route(program/messages) of my application, user can create and edit messages(using ckeditor textarea). These messages are saved in database. On another route(program/display) the application generates html site with messages(retrieved from database) created by user. The problem is that i need to update the display view(without site refresh ofc), when user change something in messages data(edit, or create new / delete). Any solution? Iam using codeigniter for backend.

Comment: if i understand well, you have bout url active at the same time, and if one user in messages update info you want to update it in display at the same time, isn´t?  If yes, you need to refresh automaticaly display by ajax

Answer (score 0):

Your view page must contain an ajax script. Which will check for database changes upon certain interval. That's all. I think ajax is new for you. Please grab a bit more AJAX concept. It's pretty handy ..

You can see W3school --
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

If you are in a hurry .. then ..
https://thenewboston.com/videos.php?cat=61

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> Jquery `ajax()` function
>   Javascript `setInterval()` function

Set the interval to certain time which will execute the ajax function to see if there is certain change in the database. if there is a change then update the view in success of ajax call. 
There is another solution by using `triggers in the database`. But I am not quite sure about this.

Comment: thx for answer, and how can i check for database change? Do i have to check all values and compare them with old values or there is some more elegant way?

Comment: I think you should triggers for that. Lets say you made an update and on that update, you insert updated data into the log table using triggers with the time stamp. In your ajax call, send in the certain time from which you can compare with the date in the log table. if the time stamp in the log table is greater than the time you passed, then you can do what ever you want. You can send time by taking current time stamp - (minus) the time for which your interval is executed.